# Page title in post query

Tags: query-posts

How do i add the current post/page title in a post query?

I've tried this, doesn't work:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10category_name=&' . $post->post_title); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: what are you trying to query for exactly?

Comment: do you mean $post->post_title = category

Comment: I want the category_name to be the page title

Comment: I want to query a specific category, the category being the same as page title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code has a typo - the ampersand is used to separate arguments, so it should be:

```
'posts_per_page=10&category_name=' . $post->post_title
```

However, since this is a new query in addition to the default, a new instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) should be used instead of `query_posts`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category_name' => $post->post_title
);

$related = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $related->have_posts() ):
    while( $related->have_posts() ):
        $related->the_post();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

To others who wants to use this,

This solution makes a page into a category page, an easy way to get categories into a header navigation that lists pages.

Just make this code into a page template and set a title that matches the category you want to show.

```
<?php 

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 10, 'category_name' => $post->post_title );

$related = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $related->have_posts() ): while( $related->have_posts() ): $related->the_post();

?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```